# Merch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'merch_id' django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a bandpage and trying to have merchandise items show up on the page but I'm getting a Merch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'merch_id' I've tried to change my views.py and urls.py any halp would be awesome.

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import merch
from django.template import loader

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello you're at the Nowhere fast homepage.")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the about band.")

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the contact page.")

def songs(request, song_id):
    return HttpResponse("%s." % song_id)

def shows(request, show_id):
    return HttpResponse("%s." % show_id)

def Merch(request, merch_id):
    merch_list = merch.objects.get(pk=merch_id)
    context = {'merch_list': merch_list}
    return render(request, 'bandpage/index.html', context)


# def index(request, merch_id):
#     merch_list = Merch.objects.order_by('name', merch_id)[:5]
#     output = ', '.join([p.name for p in merch_list])
#     return render(request, 'bandpage/index.html', {'merch_list':merch_list})

# def index(request):
#     merch_list = Merch.objects.order_by('name')[:5]
#     template = loader.get_template('bandpage/index.html')
#     context = {
#         'merch_list': merch_list,
#     }
#     return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

you can see some of the comment out code of things I've tried here.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
        path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
        path('songs/', views.songs, name='songs'),
        path('shows/', views.shows, name='shows'),
        path('merch/', views.Merch, name='Merch'),
    ]
```

I also tried it with this in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('songs/', views.songs, name='songs'),
    path('shows/', views.shows, name='shows'),
    path('merch/<int:merch_id>/', views.Merch, name='Merch'),
]
```

with this one I got the 404 page not found error.

Comment: First of all, a capitalised method and a lowercase model class are bad style, and will cause confusion in legibility of this code. Please adhere to [Python naming conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Secondly, you need to report what URL you are trying to access, if you are reporting 404 as a problem.

Comment: `path('merch/<int:merch_id>/', views.Merch, name='Merch')` - yes, this is the correct way to pass `merch_id` to `def Merch(request, merch_id)`.

Comment: `merch_list = merch.objects.get(pk=merch_id)` - no, this will never be a list, only a single record. For list view make another view method with no merch_id parameter and `merch.objects.all()` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Renamed and fixed my views works now.